# symfony i18n objects (Doctrine) get specific culture

Tags: php, internationalization, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am having an issue where I cannot retrieve a specific translation from my i18n doctrine objects. If I call `$object->getName();` I get the name in the current culture as expected. However, if I wish to retrieve a specific translation without switching the user culture... `$object->getName('fr');` I still get the current culture instead of French in this example. This `$object->getTranslation()->fr->name;` does work though. What am I doing wrong? Isn't `$object->getName($culture);` the correct way to do this?

Here is the relevant part of my schema if that's helpful:

```
Object:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    I18n:
      fields:           [name, description]
  columns:
    name:               { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    description:        { type: string(1000) }
    user_id:            { type: integer }
  relations:
    User:               { class: sfGuardUser, local: user_id, foreign: id, type: one, foreignType: many, foreignAlias: Objects }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Translation['fr']->getName()
```

alternatively:

```
$translations = $this->getTranslations();
$translations['fr']->getName();
```

Comment: So is $object->getName('fr'); the symfony 1.0 way? I was under the impression this should work for 1.4 also.

Comment: Ok, I must have something setup wrong... When I try your first solution, I get: Unknown method ObjectTranslation::getName. If I use ->name instead of ->getName(), it works. When I try your second solution, I get: Unknown record property / related component "translations" on "Object" I have never had any issues doing this sort of thing before, but I have primarily work on symfony 1.0 sites, so maybe I am just missing some crucial 1.4 step.

Answer (score 0):

This almost the same problem as on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14988309/569101), use:

```
$object->Translation['fr']->name;
$object->Translation['en']->name;
$object->Translation['it']->name;
// etc ...
```

I quote the comment I post on the other question:

> `->getName()` works if you are on the object direclty, like
>   `$object->getName()`. But if you hit the Translation relation, I never
>   used a getter to retrieve value.

By the way, I didn't remember that we can use this `$object->getName('fr');` with sf1.0.

Comment: `$object->getName('fr');` is the way the [documentation shows](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/13-I18n-and-L10n#chapter_13_sub_using_the_generated_i18n_objects) and is the way I have always done it before... for some reason on my current project, it is not working. Quoting from the documentation, "So basically, you should never have to deal with the i18n objects directly, but instead pass the culture to the model (or let it guess it) each time you do a query with the regular objects." By the way, the getter is working fine for me, I just can't specify the culture.

Comment: Well, I guess I don't need to use this method. I just always thought this was the proper way. In my current scenario, your solution will work, as does `$object->getTranslation()->fr->name;` like I mentioned in my question. I guess as long as there is nothing wrong with doing it this way, I can proceed. I still wish I knew why the other way wasn't working...