# symfony i18n objects without output escaping

Tags: internationalization, escaping, symfony-1.4

I am having a problem in Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine with getting the value of an i18n object without output escaping.

Typically I just do this `$object->getDescription(ESC_RAW);` to get the value un-escaped. The problem comes in when I want to get a specific translation of the object. How do I specify the culture and the escaping strategy? I haven't found any documentation on this. Can I pass multiple parameters as an array or something similar to this: `$object->getDescription(array('fr', ESC_RAW));`?

Here's the relevant portion of my schema:

```
Object:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    I18n:
      fields:           [name, description]
  columns:
    name:               { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    description:        { type: string(1000) }
    user_id:            { type: integer }
  relations:
    User:               { class: sfGuardUser, local: user_id, foreign: id, type: one, foreignType: many, foreignAlias: Objects }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sfOutputEscaper::unescape($object->Translation['fr']->description);
```

Comment: Hey thanks this is working. Any idea why the previous answer doesn't work for me? This doesn't seem like the proper way to handle this.

Comment: `getDescription(ESC_RAW)` work if you are on the object direclty, like `$object->getDescription(ESC_RAW)`. But if you hit the Translation relation, I never used a getter to retrieve value. By the way, using `sfOutputEscaper::unescape` isn't a bad way, it's just up to the developper since, with `ESC_RAW`, they perform the same action at the end.

Comment: Would you mind looking at my related question regarding [i18n](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14987859/1700608)? If you don't have time that's fine; I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $object->Translation['fr']->getDescription(ESC_RAW);
```

This should do the trick :)

Comment: Thanks! However when I try this I get: "Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException Unknown method ObjectTranslation::getDescription" I edited my question to include my schema. Perhaps I am doing i18n wrong.